# Build and Deploy pipelines with same version

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I would like to specify the (SemVer) version number during a (not selfhosted) DevOps release, so that DLLs will have this version number embedded in them, and I can create a release to GitHub + NuGet with the same version.

However, I'm struggling with how to accomplish this with as much automation as possible.

I know I can use the `/p:Version=x.y.z` during build to set a specific version, but if I build one more time I shouldn't use the same version number again, which could be fixed by appending `+buildnumber` to the version. This build number is not something I neccessarilly would want in the actual release, though.

So, how should I best handle version numbers during build and deploy, without having to edit some variables every time?

Comment: So do you want to increment the version in each build automatically without using the Build Number?

Comment: Not neccessarilly. Preferrably I would set the version number during the release, then the DLLs (and nuspec) is updated with that version. Another option could be reading the version number from the branch in the repo everything is built from, or maybe even define the major.minor.patch in some global config, then have the release use that setting as well for releases. Basically I'd like to streamline building and releasing with regards to version numbering without having to change a lot of settings for each release.

Comment: The versioning should be in the build, not in the release. you can store the version in a file, read in during the build and make the DLLs with this version (and increment it each build if you want).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I haven't had a chance to try it yet, but I'll probably look at it this weekend (private project and all :). Thanks for checking in, though, as I'll probably have more questions when I get started again.

Answer (score 0):

> how should I best handle version numbers during build and deploy, without having to edit some variables every time?

If you want to increment the version in build/release automatically, the `buildnumber` should be a good choice.

In generally, we defined the `major.minor.patch` in Variables or some config file, and use it with `BuildNumber` in the `Build number format` option:

[image]

Then, we could use the option use the build number as nuget version when we pack the nuget package:

[image]

For the release, we could use the parameter `$(Build.buildnumber)` to get the build number and set it as release version:

[image]

Now, we could handle version numbers with same version during build and release, without having to edit some variables every time.

Hope this helps.